# Tuples index access via contract's input params

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I'm trying to get tuple value by index using contract's input param. Getting weird assertion error.

```
let%entry main = (idx: int, storage) => { 
  let tmp = ("test - 1","test - 2", 3)
  failwith(tmp[idx])
```

`Unhandled exception "Assert_failure ./liquidity/tools/liquidity/liquidCheck.ml:1890:7"`

But accessing via just int works `failwith(tmp[1])`.

Do we have any limitations here?

Answer (score 1):

tuples indexing can only work with static constant indexes in languages with static typing like Liquidity and OCaml, otherwise you cannot know the type of an expression like (1, "string", true)[x] without knowing the value of x(which you don't at compilation time)

(c) doublexone